# How to install python win32 libs to maya 2014?

Tags: python, winapi, dll, maya

I use maya 2014 (python 2.7.3 x64) and Python 2.7.12 x64 on my computer.

I wrote a script that gets the owner of a file. The script uses library win32 and I installed it to Python. I installed library win32_x64_v.220 and it all worked:

```
import win32security

def getOwner(fname):
    sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(fname, win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
    owner_sid = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorOwner ()
    name, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountSid('storage', owner_sid)
    return (domain, name)
```

Once everything is working, it is necessary to make the script work within Maya. I tried to transfer all the folders named win32 to the maya site-pakages. Nothing succeeded. On the internet, it is advised to add them to the library search path of the following:

```
sys.path.append("C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages")
sys.path.append("C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/win32")
sys.path.append("C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/win32/lib")
sys.path.append("C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/pythonwin")
```

and when I try to run:

```
import win32security
```

it raises an error:

```
Error: ImportError: file <maya console> line 1: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

For some reason the library is not loaded ... what should I do?

Comment: You can try to append the path to your system path on windows. You can do that if you type `Environment variables` in the start menu search box. If that also doesn't work, it's probably better to just contact Autodesk support. You/your company paid a lot of money for Maya, so I'm pretty sure they'll help you.

Comment: Are you sure that the binaries for your DLL/module combo are compatible with Python 2.7.3? I suspect you're probably dealing with binaries compiled against different versions of the windows SDK.  Maya 2014 is compiled against VS 2010: http://around-the-corner.typepad.com/adn/2013/06/maya-compiler-versions-update.html

Comment: @theodox in page of the win32 library says about compatibility: Python 2.7.2+ ... [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 - https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/ . In the changelog say: Since build 217: Python 3.3 version is built with VS2010. - but nothing about 2.7 version (( http://pywin32.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pywin32/pywin32/raw-file/tip/CHANGES.txt . I did not find another data about compiler...